# C# Error message: Cannot Implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, class, multidimensional-array

The code below throws the following exception:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Clarity.DevTest.Exercises.ChessPosition' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<
>   Clarity.DevTest.Exercises.ChessPosition>'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can someone explain to me whats going wrong and why it cant return the result?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Clarity.DevTest.Exercises
{
public class Exercise1
{
    public IEnumerable<ChessPosition> GetLegalMoves(ChessPosition rookToMove, ChessPosition friendlyRook, ChessPosition enemyRook1, ChessPosition enemyRook2)
    {

        //create array to hold positions
        ChessPosition[,] coords = new ChessPosition [8,8];
        //set the Rooks into the correct places on the array
        //eg rookToMove.X = 4, rookToMove.Y = 5, "R" would be places in 4,5
        coords[rookToMove.X, rookToMove.Y] = "R";
        coords[friendlyRook.X, friendlyRook.Y] = "F";
        coords[enemyRook1.X, enemyRook1.Y] = "1";
        coords[enemyRook2.X, enemyRook2.Y] = "2";

        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        ChessPosition result = new ChessPosition(4, 5);
        return result;
    }
}

public partial class ChessPosition
{
    public ChessPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        //check to see if out of bounds
        if (x < 1 || x > 8 || y < 1 || y > 8)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("x and y must be in the range 1-8");
        }
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a single `ChessPosition` instead of an Enumerable collection of results.

Either return an enumerable collection:

```
ChessPosition result = new ChessPosition(4, 5);
IEnumerable<ChessPosition> results = new List<ChessPosition>();
results.Add(result);

return results;
```

or change your return type:

```
public ChessPosition GetLegalMoves(
    ChessPosition rookToMove, ChessPosition friendlyRook, ChessPosition 
    enemyRook1, ChessPosition enemyRook2)
```

Answer (score 2):

your method says it's returning a `IEnumerable<ChessPosition>` but you actually return a `ChessPosition`.

your method signature is:

```
public IEnumerable<ChessPosition> GetLegalMoves(...
```

So you are telling anyone who accesses that method they will receive a collection of `ChessPosition`.

But you return:

```
ChessPosition result = new ChessPosition(4, 5);
return result;
```

which is not a collection, but a single `ChessPosition`.

You need to decide whether your method returns either a single `ChessPosition`, or many.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of your method 'GetLegalMoves' does not match what you are returning - change the return type to remove the ienumerable, so it's just returning 'ChessPosition'